# Simple question about the SPI clock for Intel Edison

Tags: spi, edison

I am doing a project with an Intel Edison Arduino breakout board.

http://store.arduino.cc/product/E000052

http://download.intel.com/support/edison/sb/edisonmodule_hg_331189002.pdf

I have a device that I want to communicate with by SPI.  This device can receive a maximum of 16MHz for its clock.  I want this maximum speed of 16 MHz.  From what I understand, the Edison can output a clock speed of 19.2 MHz.

I don't know much about clocks and I am still learning.  Is it possible to program the Edison to operate its SPI output clock at a speed of 16 MHz?  If so, how would this be done?

Comment: `SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV2);` would make it run at 9.6mHz

Comment: Is it only possible to divide the clock by 2?  Not by decimal numbers?

Comment: Look into the function [mraa_spi_frequency](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa/blob/ffcf3d7d07dd46f7027e28778a9a760f6ff88264/src/spi/spi.c#L196-L207).